# Can't polling my pytelegrambot with Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

hi i'm iranian in my countries telegram don't work.and now i have code for the bot in telegram :

```
import time
from telebot import apihelper
bot_token='1172932288:AAErXFDp0FWITHbb4tgCt7MxQ33MV2nctoc'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "hessssam, how are you doing?")

bot.polling()
bot.polling(timeout=200)
```

and i have bot in telegram, but don't work it.
indeed i can't connection with telegram even proxy!
help me please!

Comment: Have you tried using a VPN?

Comment: This question seems to be related to networking, probably you are likely to get answers on other stackExchange site related to networking. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)